# The method add(TestList) in the type List<TestList> is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections

I am a beginner in Java and I am trying to learn the concept of a List by creating simple programs. So basically, I have two java files: CallListClass.java and TestList.java.

CallListClass.java

```
package javaSrc;

import java.util.*;

public class CallListClass {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        List<TestList> tl = new ArrayList<TestList>();
        //TestList tlobj = new TestList();
        TestList l1 = new TestList();
        l1.setname("MARY");
        System.out.println("Value of name::"+l1.getname());
        tl.add(l1.getname()); //Error on this line-The method add(TestList) in the type List<TestList> is not applicable for the arguments (String)
    }
}
```

TestList.java

```
package javaSrc;

public class TestList{

    int age;
    String name ="";
    int empid;

    int getage()
    {
        return this.age;
    }

    String getname()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    int getempid()
    {
        return this.empid;
    }

    void setage(int age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }

    void setname(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    void setempid(int empid)
    {
        this.empid = empid;
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why `List`'s `add` method is giving the above compilation error? Also please let me know if my TestList.java is possible in a real world scenario?

Comment: You're trying to add text to a list of lists. That's not allowed. What are you trying to do?

Comment: `tl.add(l1)` would work

Comment: Have you tried reading and making sense of the error message? It says that you're trying to call a method `add(TestList)`, taking a TestList as argument, with a String as argument. A String is not a TestList.

Comment: `tl` is a list of `TestList`. You can add instances of `TestList` to it, not instances of `String`. If you want to add strings to your list, you need a `List<String>` .

Comment: I am thinking of creating a list with name,age and empid. Is there a way we can achieve this?

Comment: Except for stylistic and naming issues, what you have is fine. Just don't try adding a String to a List<Employee> (which is how your TestList class should be named).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am thinking of creating a list with name,age and empid. Is there a way we can achieve this?

Change the error line to

```
tl.add(l1);
```

It's just that simple.

Everything you did is correct until the above line. You created a class `TestList`, which is basically a group of name, age and empid. You created a list that can store `TestList`: `new ArrayList<TestList>()`. The only thing you failed to do was to put stuff into the list. You don't need to put each name, age and empid into the list, just put the whole `l1` object in there, because that is what the `ArrayList` is supposed to store!

Also, there are some other small issues. You should name your class a more meaningful name than `TestList`. You should also rename `getname` to `getName`, `getage` to `getAge`, etc.

Comment: Thank you! I am aware of the naming conventions but I was focusing mainly on logic. Next time I will post the meaningful names :)

Comment: @S_T If you think an answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Answer (score 0):

The method `l1.add()` has the signature `List<TestList>.add(TestList value)`, so the added value should be of type `TestList`. However, the result of `l1.getName()` is a `String` and can therefore not be added to the list. For example:

```
    List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>();

    MyObject obj = new MyObject();

    //Not correct
    list.add(obj.getClass());
    list.add(obj.toString());

    //Correct
    list.add(obj);
```

Replacing `tl.add(l1.getname());` with `tl.add(l1);` should solve your problem.